Failing to setup mat-datepicker in angular component
Migrating an application from ng 15 (I think) to 18.
I'm having a headache with a date picker component.
I've removed my implementation (with bindings) and replaced with one from a tutorial (angular university).
I keep hitting "ERROR TypeError: i is null".
If I remove any reference to mat-datepicker in my template, I don't get that error.
So I suspect it's something about my component/project setup and importing stuff incorrectly.
In part of my efforts to migrate to ng 18 I ended up adding stuff to main.ts (might have even added the file), I've ended up with module imports in there as well as the component, which I suspect my not be needed.
So 3 questions:

What is best way to track down an error that doesn't see very descriptive to me (I understand null vars, but no indication what is null)?
What am I doing wrong with my date-picker setup?
Do I need both imports in component AND module imports in main.ts?

My component.ts:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-edit',
    templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss'],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [MatFormField, MatHint, MatLabel, MatInput, FormsModule,
              MatDatepicker, MatDatepickerInput, MatDatepickerToggle,
              MatSuffix,
              MatTabGroup, MatTab, NgFor, ExaminerComponent, RefereeComponent, MatButton]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [MatFormField, MatHint, MatLabel, MatInput, FormsModule, MatDatepicker, MatDatepickerInput, MatDatepickerToggle, MatSuffix, MatTabGroup, MatTab, NgFor, MatButton]
})
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
.. removed for brevity ..
}

Component.html:
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

Main.ts
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    appConfig.providers,
    [provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection()],
    importProvidersFrom(
      FormsModule,
      FontAwesomeModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatSnackBarModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatTabsModule,
      MatMenuModule,
      LoggerModule.forRoot({level: !environment.production ? NgxLoggerLevel.DEBUG : NgxLoggerLevel.OFF})),
    {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 50000}},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DATE_FORMATS},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'},
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    provideAnimations()
  ]
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));


please share a simple stackblitz with the issue replicated, will be good for debugging

See that, when you use standalone components you should imports modules or another components standalone, e.g. should be:imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatInputMatInputModule, FormsModule, MatDatepickerModule,...]. NOTE: In the examples in material angular you can see the code to know what modules you should import

Thanks for the suggestion @Eliseo
I have removed imports of individual components from my component imports, I have removed Mat* imports in my main.ts.
No improvement.

Try to import the modules in your component (instead of import the components) and not use importProvidersFrom when you bootstrap the aplication.

Please add the below line in your app.component.ts:
providers: [provideNativeDateAdapter()]

app.components.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { provideNativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [provideNativeDateAdapter()],
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatDatepickerModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'] // Ensure this path is correct
})
export class AppComponent {

}


Thank you so much!
I ended up adding to main.ts rather than the component, but that is what I was missing.
